# Regular expression with possible hyphen and then a limited number of words characters

Tags: regex

I need a regex to match expressions which contain the string OKAY then a possible hyphen, and then zero or one word characters. after this any non-word-character is accepted and then anything. for expressions which match, OKAY will be changed to OK if there is no word-character following, and to e.g: OA if the letter following is A. if the hyphen exists it is dropped.

```
OKAY         =>       OK
OKAY-        =>       OK
OKAYA        =>       OA
OKAY-A       =>       OA
OKAYAB       =>       OKAYAB          (no-match)
OKAY-AB      =>       OKAY-AB         (no-match)
```

examples may be followed by e.g: .CD without changing the results

```
OKAY.CD         =>       OK.CD
OKAY-.CD        =>       OK.CD
OKAYA.CD        =>       OA.CD
OKAY-A.CD       =>       OA.CD
OKAYAB.CD       =>       OKAYAB.CD          (no-match)
OKAY-AB.CD      =>       OKAY-AB.CD         (no-match)
```

my problem implementing this was that since both the hyphen and the word-character are optional, I get "lazy" matches which match also the non-wanted cases.
for the sake of education I would appreciate examples both with and without look-aheads (if possible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a regex that should work for you:

```
\bOKAY(?>-?)(\w)?([^\w\s]\S*)?(?!\S)
```

Since it isn't clear what language you are using, here is pseudo code for how you would do the replacement.

```
"O" + (match.group(1) if match.group(1) else "K") + match.group(2)
```

Here is a rubular: http://www.rubular.com/r/SE8MBkUUUo

---

**edit:** I made some changes in the above regex after the comments, but the description below does not reflect those changes.  Here are the changes from the original regex:

- Changed `^` to `\b` so it doesn't need to start at beginning of line
- `\W` became `[^\w\s]`, this prevents `OKAY OKAY` from being one match
- Changed `.*` to `\S*` so the match will end at whitespace
- Changed `$` to `(?!\S)`, `(?!\S)` means "only match if we are at the end of the string or the next character is whitespace", could also be written as `(?=\s|\z)`

---

The really tricky part here is that a regex like `^OKAY-?(\w)?(\W.*)?$` looks like it would work, but it does not for a case like `OKAY-AB` because in the end both the `-?` and the `(\w)?` will not match, and then `(\W.*)?` will match the remainder of the string.

What we need to do to fix this is make it so `-?` will not backtrack.  This would be simple if [possessive quantifiers](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFAQFjAA&url=http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html&ei=QDC9T6DTF8WTiQKSs5WPDg&usg=AFQjCNG_uUyN-AGGcy7-8dfAnE4DhRIErQ&sig2=_ETtI54xJnRH-xdM0_QGIQ) were supported by .NET, then we could just change it to `-?+`.

Unfortunately they aren't supported, so we need to use [atomic grouping](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html) instead.  `(?>-?)` will optionally match a `-`, but will forget all backtracking information as soon as it exits the group.  Note that the atomic group does not capture, so `(\w)?` is capture group 1.

Comment: some issues: 1. must lose the leading caret ^ , as OP did not define that the expression should begin the string.

2. if there are several OKAY on the same line, only the first is matched correctly

Comment: @eyaler - 1. Okay I replaced the leading `^` with `\b`, but you can remove that as well if it is legal for `OKAY` to be preceded by other word characters.  2. The *and then anything* portion of your description is a little bit misleading if you do not want to match until the end of the line, do you mean any non-whitespace characters?  I changed the regex to that by changing the `.` to `\S` (non-whitespace characters). 3. `\Z` and `\z` are end of string anchors, so changing the `.` to `\Z` completely changes the regex and changing `$` to `\z` doesn't really change it at all.

Comment: I edited my regex, added some explanation, and updated the Rubular.  It should now properly handle multiple matches on a single line.

Comment: thanks. i found the following to work for me: for matching with capturing of the trailing letter: OKAY(?>-?)(\w)?(\W|\z) , and for matching without capturing the letter: OKAY(?>-?)(?!\w{2,}) . these relax the assumption of white space between OKAY's.

Answer (score 1):

To do this without lookaheads, you can use

```
^(OKAY)(((-\w?|\w)(\W.*)?)|[^-\w].*)?$
```

This matches the word "OKAY" and then an optional group containing *either* a `-`, an optional word character, and then an optional non-word-character followed by anything group, *or* a character that is not a `-` or a word character followed by anything. The `^` and `$` match the start and end of the string respectively, so it will only match exactly the acceptable strings.

Lookaheads would barely make a difference. The only change would be to put a lookahead (`(?=...)`) around everything after the "OKAY" group.

To use this with .net, the only change needed would be to escape all of the `\` in the string.

Comment: this will partially match the unwanted cases above

Comment: Can you say which case it will match? Then I can fix it

Comment: it will match the OKAY-A part of OKAY-AB

Comment: @eyaler - See my answer for explanation of that behavior.

Comment: @eyaler I think I fixed my regex now

Answer (score 1):

Don't know .NET regex, but this is a start with preg-style matching:

`OKAY-?(\w?)([^\w-]\w+)?\s*$`

If $1 is empty, then output is OK$2

Otherwise, output is O$1$2.

Comment: This assumes that there can be no hyphens unless they immediately follow `OKAY`, so `OKAY-A-BC` would not match.